# Debugging Xamarin

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin

I'm trying to show the CallLog
I'm getting an error, but it only shows 80 chars for 1 second and then the message pops away.
The error is something like: permission denial "opening provider com." and then it's cut off.

Any way to see what the error is?

I'm using live player from Visual Studio.

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Try check the output log, the xamarin debugger isn't too useful

Comment: Do you mean the output shown in VS? The last thing it says is: Deploy to OnePlus ONEPLUS A3003 Player succeeded.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you was using the Live Player by Xamarin. That thing has a ton of bad reviews, and I personally just use the normal push to device functionality, and this logs exceptions via VS

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to Try and catch. Send an email

```
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            SendEmail(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void SendEmail(Exception ex)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
        i.SetType("message/rfc822");
        i.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, new String[] { "rosendal@gmail.com" });
        i.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "exception");
        i.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, ex.ToString());
        try
        {
            Context myContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
            myContext.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            //                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```